# Angular variables not updating outside loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, angularjs-scope, models

So I'm running into a weird issue with Angular where I created a raw predefined object to loop through card stats for a card game I am working on.

```
    $scope.attack = 500;
    $scope.defense = 500;

    $scope.cardPowers = [
    {
      name: "balanced",
      attack: 2500,
      defense: 1500,
      cost: 3
    },
    {
      name: "high-offense",
      attack: 2500,
      defense: 1000,
      cost: 5
    },
    {
      name: "base-offense",
      attack: 1800,
      defense: 1000,
      cost: 4
    }
  ];
```

This is all in the main controller where most of my functionality is going through. I'm looping through them and creating buttons where someone can choose the attributes for the car like so:

```
<div id="preview" class="vertical-display card twenty-five building" ng-class="{'building': gotComics, 'editing' : editing}" ng-controller="Save">
{{attack}} : {{defense}}
<h3>Card Builder</h3>
<div class="card-functions">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" ng-click="saveNewCard(cardName, cardDescription, 500, 500, 5, cardThumbnail, cardBackground, '1', cardType)">SAVE <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="" ng-click="editing = true">EDIT <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="" ng-click="editing = false" ng-show="editing">CLOSE <i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
  <!-- <a href="" ng-click="saveImage()" class="button small saveImage"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i> Save as Image</a> -->
</div>
<div ng-show="editing" class="options">
  <h4>Choose Power</h4>
  <p ng-repeat="power in cardPowers"><a href="" ng-click="attack=power.attack">{{power.name | uppercase}}       {{attack}}</a></p>

  <h4>Thumbnail Positioning</h4>

  <!-- repeat card positioning -->  
</div>

<div ng-show="gotComics">
  <?php include('flip-container-code.php'); ?>
</div>
```

Mostly everything works fine, however, when I click on my button to set the new attack, it only updates {{attack}} inside the loop, and not outside. See this screencast to see what I am talking about: http://screencast.com/t/0ZukLLYqtUYM

Not sure why this is happening, did some research and it seems I am doing this all right, so it's odd. Note: Everything else is actually working just fine, my card saving function, seeing the default attack and defense values, the models, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, you should move the implementation details outside of the view (i.e., you shouldn't be directly setting `model.attack = power.attack` in the view, that should be *at least* one level deeper, in the controller).  With that, moving this to the controller will resolve your issue itself.

Your view can look like this:

```
<p ng-repeat="power in cardPowers">
  <a href="" ng-click="setAttackPower(power)">
    {{power.name | uppercase}} {{attack}}
  </a>
</p>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.setAttackPower = function(power) {
  $scope.attack = power.attack;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. This is actually something I did earlier elsewhere in the code and didn't realize it. This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem right, try to put the `attack` property inside an object. This is because when you do `attack = power.attck` inside `ng-repeat` you are creating a new property on the child scope created by the `ng-repeat` instead of changing the value of the `attack` on the parent scope.

In your controller:

```
$scope.model = {attack: 500};
```

And your html:

```
<div id="preview" class="vertical-display card twenty-five building" ng-class="{'building': gotComics, 'editing' : editing}" ng-controller="Save">
{{model.attack}} : {{defense}}
<h3>Card Builder</h3>
<div class="card-functions">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" ng-click="saveNewCard(cardName, cardDescription, 500, 500, 5, cardThumbnail, cardBackground, '1', cardType)">SAVE <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="" ng-click="editing = true">EDIT <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="" ng-click="editing = false" ng-show="editing">CLOSE <i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
  <!-- <a href="" ng-click="saveImage()" class="button small saveImage"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i> Save as Image</a> -->
</div>
<div ng-show="editing" class="options">
  <h4>Choose Power</h4>
  <p ng-repeat="power in cardPowers"><a href="" ng-click="model.attack=power.attack">{{power.name | uppercase}}       {{model.attack}}</a></p>

  <h4>Thumbnail Positioning</h4>

  <!-- repeat card positioning -->  
</div>

<div ng-show="gotComics">
  <?php include('flip-container-code.php'); ?>
</div>
```

See [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) for further explanation.

Comment: Or even make the `ng-click` be `ng-click="setAttack(power)"` and simply set `$scope.attack = power.attack` in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to accest the parent and it should work

Like this on ng-click:

```
 <p ng-repeat="power in cardPowers"><a href="" ng-click="$parent.attack = power.attack">{{power.name | uppercase}}       {{attack}}</a></p>
```

Comment: Is this accessing the parent controller? I didn't know something like this was possible. Unless I am misunderstanding.